# KendoUI datasource error event not raised on post with http 500 error

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a datasource with error handler defined as below.  In the code I am intentionally causing an error on post and the server is returning 500 plus the json data, but the error event is not being raised on post.  It does fire on the read event.  See http://www.ageektech.com/simplyfundraising  Open your browser debugger, refresh the page, click edit change any value, click update.  Need help figuring out why the error event is not triggered.

Thanks,
Dan

```
    schema : {
        model : myModel,
        data : "__ENTITIES",
          errors: function(e) {
              debugger;
  // var xhr = e.xhr;
    // var statusCode = e.status;
    // var  errorThrown = e.errorThrown;
              //alert(JSON.parse(e.responseText).error.innererror.message);
    return e.errors;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schema.errors should contain the name of the JSON field that contains error messages.
e.g. 
schema: { errors: "Errors" }

For when you are returning JSON like:
{ "Errors": "Stuff went wrong" }

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way to subscribe to the [error](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#error) event of the DataSource. The [schema.errors](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#schemaerrors-functionstring-default) setting is used for a different purpose.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, according to the schema.errors doc it is used to parse the json returned from the server when there is an error. I am getting jason back with a field __Error that I would parse in the errors function if it fired on post.  So if this is not the correct way then what is the correct way to parse errors sent from the server?

Comment: jason returned from the server when on error, docs make it seem like schema.errors is the correct place, please point me to the correct event to parse errors returned in json from the server             {"__ENTITIES":[{"__KEY":"195","__STAMP":3,"ID":195,"firstName":"c","middleName":"c","lastName":"c","ContactType":{},"addressCollection":{"__deferred":{"uri":"/rest/Contact(195)/addressCollection?$expand=addressCollection"}},"__ERROR":[{"message":"Cannot save related entity of attribute \"ContactType\" for the entity of datastore class \"Contact\"","componentSignature":"dbmg","errCode":1537}]}]}

Comment: If you are returning a valid JSON document (even containing error information), you can parse it using [`schema.parse`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#schemaparse-function) and from there, do the error processing that you want.

Comment: I think that could work, thanks.  Still I would like to know what schema.errors is used for if not to parse json error response from server.  It fires fine on read just not create or update if there is an error from the server